# A single die is rolled 13 times. What is the probability that a six is rolled exactly once, if it is known that at least one six is rolled?

Tags: probability, self-study

A single die is rolled 13 times.

What is the probability that a six is rolled exactly once, if it is known that at least one six is rolled?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You need to add the self study tag. Someone voted to closed your post because that tag is missing. It is not me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are asking for conditional probability, i.e.
P(6 rolled exactly once | 6 rolled at least once)

Note: $ P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} $

So this would be the same as calculating the probability 6 is rolled exactly once and dividing it by the probability 6 is rolled at least once.

Edit: It seems I shouldn't help if this is homework, so I'll leave it at this.